# Expanding short names for non 8dot3 directory paths to long name

Tags: r, long-filenames

In `R` on `Windows`, `tempdir()` returns a path that contains short names for `non 8dot3 directory names`.

How do I expand those to long names?

An answer that uses pure `R` code is favorable, but one that uses well-known shell commands used via `system()` is fine as a backup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [normalizePath](http://projetos.inpa.gov.br/i3geo/pacotes/r/win/library/utils/html/normalizePath.html) function will turn short names into long names:

> This converts relative paths to absolute paths, and converts short names to long names.

Comment: Excellent! I was trying file.path, path.expand,  and I even found tools::file_path_as_absolute, but none worked. Thanks!